# Unexpected Identifier SLComposerView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey everyone running into major errors where I'm being told the SLComposerViewController is unrecognizable. No visible interface for UIController and an expected identifier on my else statement when it's written correctly. It is also not recognizing my actionContoller or my twitterVC. I am in school and this is the code example I was given I have checked it and triple checked it and it is written verbatim to the intructed example which is leaving me confused as there are 12 errors in all. Any help anyone can give me to correct these errors would be great!

```
//  ViewController.m
//  SocialNetworkApp
//
//  Created by Jessy on 2/12/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 A3LeversPeer. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Social/Social.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tweetTextView;
- (void) configureTweetTextView;
- (void) showAlertMessage: (NSString *) myMessage;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *fbTextView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *socialTextView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureTweetTextView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) showAlertMessage:(NSString *) myMessage {
    UIAlertController *alertController;
    alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"TwitterShare" message:myMessage preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)tweetShareAction:(id)sender {

    if ([self.tweetTextView isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.tweetTextView resignFirstResponder];
}

UIAlertController *actionController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Tweet Notes" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    UIAlertAction *tweetAction =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Tweet"style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:
                                 ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
if([SLComposeViewController
        isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]
(SLComposeViewController *twitterVC= [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]);
}];
    //Tweet Out
    if( [self.tweetTextView.text length] <140 ) {
    [twitterVC setInitialText:self.tweetTextView.text];
}
        else{
NSString *shortText = [self.tweetTextView.text substringToIndex:140];
}

[self.presentedViewController: twitterVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else{
    //Raise Objection

    [self showAlertMessage:@"Sign in to Twitter"];
[actionController addAction:tweetAction];
[actionController addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:actionController animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void) configureTweetTextView {
    self.tweetTextView.layer.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.98
                green: 0.80                                                                                       blue: 0.93
                    alpha: 1.0].CGColor;

    self.tweetTextView.layer.cornerRadius= 10.0;
    self.tweetTextView.layer.borderColor= [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0
                                                            alpha: 0.5].CGColor;
    self.tweetTextView.layer.borderWidth= 2.0;
}

- (IBAction)fbShareAction:(id)sender {
}
- (IBAction)socialShareAction:(id)sender {
}
- (IBAction)nothingShareAction:(id)sender {
}


@end
```

Comment: Do you can copy the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
#import "Social/Social.h"
```

By:

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

**Social** is Apple's framework, so you should import it with `<>` sign.

By the way, check your `Target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries` that you included in *Social.framework*.

Comment: Thank you I've changed the #import as suggested and I double checked and I am using Social.framework in my Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Comment: However, I am still running into the same errors. It keeps saying I haven't declared my twitterVC variable it's not recognizing my UIAlertAction *tweetAction or my self.presentedtViewController